# Longest Common Prefix - Divide and Conquer approach complexity analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer, space-complexity

I am trying to understand how the time and space complexity for D&C approach of finding longest common prefix from the array of strings has been derived. Example: The array of strings is ["leet", "leetcode", "leeds","le"] and the output would be "le" It's a leetcode problem 14

Code:

```
public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) return "";    
        return longestCommonPrefix(strs, 0 , strs.length - 1);
}

private String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs, int l, int r) {
    if (l == r) {
        return strs[l];
    }
    else {
        int mid = (l + r)/2;
        String lcpLeft =   longestCommonPrefix(strs, l , mid);
        String lcpRight =  longestCommonPrefix(strs, mid + 1,r);
        return commonPrefix(lcpLeft, lcpRight);
   }
}

String commonPrefix(String left,String right) {
    int min = Math.min(left.length(), right.length());       
    for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
        if ( left.charAt(i) != right.charAt(i) )
            return left.substring(0, i);
    }
    return left.substring(0, min);
}
```

**Complexity Analysis as stated on their website**
Time Complexity: O(S), where S is the number of all characters in the array, S = m*n. Time complexity is T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(m). Therefore time complexity is O(S).
Space Complexity:O(m*log(n))

I understood the part where T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(m) but from there how did they derived m*n as time complexity. For space complexity I think we are considering height of recursion tree times cost each recursive call takes.

n is the number of strings in an array and m is the length of prefix.

Comment: What are `m` and `n` in that product?

Comment: @Prune Thanks for pointing out. I have edited the question. n is the total number of strings in an array and m is the length of prefix. In best case m would be minLength.

Comment: You *might* have better luck asking on [cs.se].

Comment: Unless you do parallelization I see absolutely no benefit of divide and conquer compared to vertical scanning, which is easier to understand and needs less space.

Comment: @maraca You are right! This is just for understanding D&C paradigm and its complexity analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m`*`n` complexity comes from that **O(m)** term.  It's replicated (executed) `n` times: at each iteration, you split the list in half (by quantity of strings, `n`), digging down until your base case gets executed once for each of the `n` strings.  Each of those carries out an **O(m)** operation.

Also, each *merge* carries out an **O(m)** operation, for a total of `2*n-1`  of those.  `2*n-1` is **O(n)**.  **O(m)** * **O(n)** is **O(mn)**.

Is that clear enough?

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense but how did we compute 2*n-1?

Comment: `n` strings processed, then `(n-1)` merges.